# Question about a forgetful 2-functor in Tom Leinster's *Higher Categories, Higher Operads*

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

In their book *Higher Operads, Higher Categories* Tom Leinster claims, that unbiased weak 2-categories may be defined as weak algebras for a strict 2-monad on the strict 2-category of **Cat**-enriched graphs. The relevant paragraph is:

> As in the case of monoidal categories there is an abstract version of the definition of unbiased bicategories phrased in the language of 2-monads. [...] now we take the 2-monad 'free strict 2-category' on **Cat-Gph**, the strict 2-category of **Cat**-graphs. [...] The 2-category structure of **Cat** induces a 2-category structure on **Cat-Gph** as follows: Given maps $P,Q:B \to B'$ of **Cat**-graphs, there are only any 2-cells of the form $P\Rightarrow Q$ when $P_0 = Q_0: B_0 \to B_0'$, and in that case a 2-cell $\zeta$ is a family of natural transformations $\zeta_{a,b}: P_{a,b} \to Q_{a,b}$. Now, there is a forgetful map **Str-2-Cat**$\to$**Cat-Gph** of 2-categories, [...]

and you can find it on page 93. The book is freely accessible on the arxiv. I do not understand the last sentence. Of course a strict 2-functor does induce a morphism of category enriched graphs. But how does a strict 2-cell $\gamma: F\Rightarrow G, C \to D$ between strict 2-functors induce a 2-cell in **Cat-Gph**?

A 2-cell of strict 2-functors consist of 1-cells $\gamma_X: FX \to GX$ for each 0-cell $X$ of $C$ such that some equations hold strictly. But nothing forces the object part of $F$ and $G$ to be equal, so how can we define a 2-cell of category enriched graphs between the underlying morphisms of $F$ and $G$? Does Tom Leinster mean icons when they speak about 2-cells in **Str-2-Cat**?